# Contact measurement

Tags: sensor, measurement, proximity-sensor, contact

I have a mechanical assembly that is to be mated to another surface. To ensure that my assembly is correctly mounted before installation, I have a test piece I insert into it. When everything is OK the test piece and the assembly comes in contact along the mating surface I mentioned. I would like to design some type of circuit that allows me to know whether these two surfaces are in contact.

I thought about using **inductive proximity sensors**, as my assembly is made out of steel, but the sensing range is **>=0.8 mm**, so I don't think they are suitable.

Does anyone have an idea of what I could use?

Comment: Are the two surfaces conductive, but electrically isolated? You might be able to use a strip of insulating material and measure capacitance between the surfaces. You might also be able to use something like pressure-sensitive tape: https://www.sensorprod.com/campaign/pressure-indicating-tape/index.php?mcode=gc-pressure. Or maybe piezo-electric film to sense pressure, https://piezopvdf.com/specialty-tape/

Comment: You should show a sketch or an image of the assembly you are talking about, There are many ways to detect alignment of mating surfaces.

Comment: IF the sensing range of the inductive prox sensors is not suitable for your application, what sort of range *is* suitable? Do you need something which will "reject" anything that's not in full contact with the surface?

Comment: shine a light between the components

Comment: Not sure if electrical contact would work for a GO/NOGO test: as soon as *any* contact is made between the two pieces, you'd have a completed circuit. If you need to measure clearance (or proximity) along a whole edge, or surface, that would be much more difficult. What's wrong with carbon paper, which leaves a mark where mating surfaces touch? If you need some automatic evaluation, use a camera to judge the areas that are marked.